# How to tokenize string in dash

Tags: dash-shell

I read data from a string that is formatted like `firstfield|secondfield|thirdfield`, in bash I use this construct to achieve this:

```
i="firstfield|secondfield|thirdfield"
defaultIFS=$IFS
IFS="|"
set -- $i
arr=( $i )
IFS=$defaultIFS

FIRST=${arr[0]}
SECOND=${arr[1]}
THIRD=${arr[2]}
```

Is it possible to get $FIRST, $SECOND and $THIRD in dash without using external programs like awk/sed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, which would also work in `bash`:

```
IFS='|' read FIRST SECOND THIRD dummy << EOF
$i
EOF
```

If there are always exactly 3 fields, you do not need the dummy variable. Note that there is no need to reset the IFS variable, since it is used local to the `read` command.

Answer (score 0):

cut with the option of -d often does the job.

```
i="firstfield|secondfield|thirdfield"  
echo $i | cut -d "|" -f1
```

`-d "|"` means to tokenize the string with delimiter "|", then `-f1` gets the first field, `-f2` gets the second filed, `-f3` gets the third field.

Answer (score 0):

Scrutinizer's `read` method works, but you can also use `set` to set the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2` etc.) which is about as close to an array you can get in `dash`. If you do this cleverly (using `local`) it can be quite useful.

Heres a little function, that splits `$STRING` on `$SEPARATOR` and then evals `$CODE` for each token. The variable `$TOKEN` is set when the eval is called, so you can use that. With a modification you could give it the token position as well. (And if you do anything advanced in your `$CODE` you might want to to reset `$IFS` as well.)

```
# Usage: foreach_token SEPARATOR STRING CODE
foreach_token() {
    local IFS="$1" STRING="$2" CODE="$3" TOKEN    # get args
    set -- $STRING                                # split $STRING on $IFS
    for TOKEN; do                                 # foreach $@
        eval "$CODE"
    done
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
foreach_token "|" "firstfield|secondfield|thirdfield" 'echo "$TOKEN"'
```